# Select onChange function is not triggering in ant design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I created Form Item .Which is contain select option .When there is no onChange function I can submit form with form value trigger.but when i add any onchange function while submitting not trigger field value

Here my code

```
<Form>
    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Provincial">
        {
            getFieldDecorator('provinsId', {
                rules: [{
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please select  provincial',
                }],
            initialValue:this.props.formDataEdit.provincialName,

        })(
        <Select onChange={this.getDistrictByProvins} placeholder="Please select category">
            {allProvins}
        </Select>
        )}
    </FormItem>
</Form>

getDistrictByProvins=()=>{//getting data from DB}
```

Comment: You could make Select a controlled component and work with it

Comment: what do you mean when you say trigger exactly?

Comment: @Lucifer its mean couldn't get selected value

Comment: you have to set the value prop of the Select Component to your value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it a controlled component.

```
<Select value={selectedOption} onChange={this.getDistrictByProvins} placeholder="Please select category">
        {allProvins}
    </Select>
```